# How to determine whether a vector is in the span of a a set of vectors modulo 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I already found out how to check whether a vector is contained in a set of vectors using Gaussian Elimination / RREF. My problem is that I can't find a way, even after researching for several hours, to factor in the modulo 2. I just need to determine whether there is a solution at all, but I really struggle with the factoring in the modulo part at some point in my calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in fact will be easier in the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Here is how you should proceed. If you want to determine if $\gamma$ is in the span of $\alpha_1 ,\alpha_2 ,\alpha_3$ (say), you write the matrix $[\alpha_1 ,\alpha_2 ,\alpha_3]^T$ this will be a matrix of $0s$ and $1s$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Reduce it to RREF. Using operations $1+1=0$,$1+0=1$,$1\times 1=1$ $1 \times 0 =0$ And your on your way.